# MySQL : Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have two tables inside my MySQL database which consists of awards and members. I want to set member_name as a foreign key into awards table instead of member_id.

I have set member_name as UNIQUE inside the members table and trying to set it as foreign key but I'm getting an error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Comment: What query are you using?  What are your `CREATE TABLE` statements?

Comment: Have you checked if any member_name in your award table does not exist in your member table, or has been written different?

Comment: this is my query @cxw - 
ALTER TABLE `awards` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`member_name`) REFERENCES `isec`.`members`(`member_name`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

Comment: @Lukas i have checked, it exists in both tables.

Comment: just create index on member_name column of members table and execute your alter query for foreign key.

Comment: @Azie Don’t add relevant information in the comments. It’s much better to use the “edit” link to improve the quality of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is showing that you are trying to insert a child row while its corresponding row does not exist in its master table. So first insert in master table then in child.

If this is not the case then you can also check that it seems you are trying to create foreign key member_name as string in member table with member_id as int in award table, while to make foreign key relationship both fields data type should be same.

If this is not the case then share your table structure and your alter query to make foreign key.

Note: Foreign key always perform with better performance by int data type than string. So you should keep member_id instead of member_name if there is no specific reason of it.

Comment: hi, this is my table structure:  **awards**:  awardsID int(11), member_name varchar(40), award_title varchar (100), level varchar(40), year_received int(11). **members**: member_id int(11),member_name varchar(40), position varchar(30), faculty varchar(10), email varchar(100), research_interests varchar(255).  **alter query**: ALTER TABLE `awards` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`member_name`) REFERENCES `isec`.`members`(`member_name`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

Comment: @Azie: If it helps you then you may choose it as answer.. :)

Comment: Good advice re. foreign keys having better performance with int data types over strings.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer this question if you provided more details on
both table structures.

In any case, the error would most likely indicate that there’s a record in the existing data set that would violate the Foreign Key constraint, i.e., a `member_name` in the `awards` table which doesn’t exist in the `members` table.